# Getting Python to read numbers from specific locations on a map of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of text files in a folder called 'inputs/' that look like this:

```
1


 channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052447 scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                             0.019                                            34
 33                                 0.042   0.054   0.043   0.015                                33
 32                             0.052   0.115   0.079   0.064   0.009                            32
 31                        0.035    0.174   0.158   0.128   0.047   0.003                        31
 30                    0.034    0.170   0.269   0.129   0.160   0.012   0.002                    30
 29                0.020   0.118    0.427   0.377   0.329   0.068   0.004   0.003                29
 28                    0.102    0.331   0.454   0.140   0.324   0.015   0.007                    28
 27                0.053   0.263    0.385   0.301   0.111   0.082   0.009   0.016                27
 26            0.017   0.151    0.509   0.194   0.102   0.100   0.039   0.027   0.019            26
 25        0.006   0.051   0.397    0.379   0.134   0.099   0.203   0.031   0.052   0.011        25
 24            0.024   0.086    0.232   0.288   0.292   0.135   0.051   0.136   0.050            24
 23        0.016   0.029   0.140    0.160   0.203   0.281   0.103   0.088   0.108   0.036        23
 22            0.047   0.096    0.178   0.341   0.402   0.347   0.079   0.249   0.118            22
 21        0.045   0.085   0.487    0.219   0.484   0.226   0.183   0.294   0.362   0.070        21
 20    0.017   0.132   0.215    0.683   0.192   0.470   0.482   0.197   0.173   0.143   0.032    20
 19        0.087   0.374   0.442    0.493   0.191   0.206   0.511   0.358   0.188   0.142        19
 18    0.030   0.204   0.532    0.504   0.147   0.193   0.212   0.478   0.248   0.424   0.054    18
 17        0.104   0.365   0.324    0.144   0.361   0.378   0.245   0.717   0.469   0.185        17
 16    0.031   0.205   0.185    0.104   0.135   0.238   0.217   0.577   0.466   0.302   0.061    16
 15        0.090   0.357   0.096    0.090   0.458   0.269   0.513   0.569   0.203   0.173        15
 14    0.023   0.137   0.148    0.097   0.192   0.567   0.529   0.232   0.301   0.343   0.052    14
 13        0.053   0.125   0.260    0.332   0.577   0.558   0.351   0.127   0.121   0.134        13
 12    0.012   0.054   0.375    0.116   0.204   0.305   0.264   0.079   0.100   0.122   0.035    12
 11        0.039   0.127   0.251    0.107   0.472   0.524   0.126   0.067   0.147   0.109        11
 10            0.120   0.189    0.056   0.249   0.212   0.420   0.051   0.282   0.311            10
  9        0.044   0.383   0.156    0.063   0.182   0.187   0.116   0.135   0.381   0.096         9
  8            0.146   0.449    0.113   0.104   0.391   0.102   0.189   0.173   0.156             8
  7        0.027   0.227   0.461    0.144   0.292   0.098   0.305   0.558   0.099   0.032         7
  6            0.066   0.231    0.436   0.182   0.125   0.138   0.593   0.170   0.046             6
  5                0.097   0.128    0.483   0.177   0.154   0.242   0.553   0.064                 5
  4                    0.080    0.132   0.501   0.153   0.511   0.218   0.146                     4
  3                0.021   0.046    0.160   0.422   0.475   0.455   0.109   0.030                 3
  2                    0.020    0.054   0.231   0.162   0.208   0.098   0.036                     2
  1                        0.014    0.084   0.167   0.161   0.137   0.026                         1
  0                             0.022   0.091   0.092   0.086   0.034                             0
 -1                                 0.025   0.055   0.052   0.031                                -1
 -2                                             0.021                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel averaged  cell avg  thermal fluxes    core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                              0.11                                            34
 33                                  0.15    0.27    0.27    0.14                                33
 32                              0.22    0.42    0.53    0.40    0.19                            32
 31                         0.23     0.57    0.71    0.70    0.52    0.20                        31
 30                     0.21     0.71    0.85    1.05    0.82    0.58    0.18                    30
 29                 0.13    0.71     0.99    1.03    1.05    0.97    0.56    0.14                29
 28                     0.60     1.19    1.15    1.43    1.15    0.98    0.51                    28
 27                 0.44    1.12     1.41    1.21    1.60    1.37    0.93    0.42                27
 26             0.25    0.98     1.48    1.44    1.67    1.67    1.34    0.86    0.28            26
 25         0.11    0.79    1.40     1.65    1.67    1.83    1.53    1.30    0.74    0.13        25
 24             0.53    1.40     1.91    1.70    1.68    1.86    1.70    1.13    0.58            24
 23         0.23    1.10    1.89     2.11    1.73    1.80    1.97    1.67    1.12    0.32        23
 22             0.73    1.68     2.10    2.00    1.85    1.87    2.04    1.46    0.87            22
 21         0.36    1.32    1.73     2.26    2.05    1.95    2.25    1.79    1.28    0.56        21
 20     0.10    0.82    1.80     1.34    2.53    2.14    2.05    2.23    1.89    1.21    0.19    20
 19         0.45    1.18    1.86     2.13    2.64    2.43    2.06    1.89    1.74    0.70        19
 18     0.15    0.80    1.46     2.02    2.68    2.65    2.42    1.96    1.92    1.14    0.24    18
 17         0.48    1.02    1.87     2.54    2.48    2.34    2.11    1.29    1.49    0.73        17
 16     0.16    0.81    1.47     2.33    2.65    2.64    2.47    1.98    1.70    1.17    0.26    16
 15         0.50    1.13    1.95     2.43    2.37    2.40    2.16    1.90    1.49    0.71        15
 14     0.16    0.92    1.72     2.16    2.42    2.21    2.14    2.44    1.82    1.07    0.24    14
 13         0.52    1.44    1.82     1.97    2.05    2.08    2.21    2.30    1.64    0.69        13
 12     0.12    0.99    1.57     2.11    1.94    2.06    2.04    2.42    2.03    1.22    0.19    12
 11         0.43    1.43    1.86     2.13    1.85    1.97    2.32    2.27    1.61    0.58        11
 10             0.81    1.78     2.17    1.89    2.18    1.92    2.37    1.79    0.92            10
  9         0.25    1.07    2.01     2.18    1.84    2.18    2.22    2.24    1.28    0.38         9
  8             0.56    1.35     2.17    2.12    1.91    1.79    2.31    1.87    0.76             8
  7         0.11    0.82    1.56     2.18    1.94    2.16    2.00    1.81    1.23    0.17         7
  6             0.27    1.09     1.73    2.14    2.21    2.13    1.88    1.56    0.45             6
  5                 0.48    1.40     1.69    2.11    2.17    2.14    1.50    0.77                 5
  4                     0.71     1.53    1.61    2.05    1.76    1.84    0.98                     4
  3                 0.16    0.84     1.46    1.50    1.58    1.48    1.18    0.27                 3
  2                     0.25     0.91    1.19    1.51    1.48    1.16    0.37                     2
  1                         0.27     0.78    1.01    1.12    0.94    0.43                         1
  0                              0.28    0.59    0.78    0.72    0.36                             0
 -1                                  0.21    0.39    0.42    0.25                                -1
 -2                                              0.17                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052447 scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                             0.019                                            34
 33                                 0.042   0.054   0.043   0.015                                33
 32                             0.052   0.115   0.079   0.064   0.009                            32
 31                        0.035    0.174   0.158   0.128   0.047   0.003                        31
 30                    0.034    0.170   0.269   0.147   0.161   0.013   0.002                    30
 29                0.020   0.118    0.313   0.277   0.240   0.078   0.004   0.003                29
 28                    0.102    0.274   0.336   0.160   0.236   0.018   0.007                    28
 27                0.053   0.224    0.327   0.241   0.127   0.094   0.010   0.016                27
 26            0.017   0.151    0.375   0.222   0.117   0.116   0.045   0.030   0.019            26
 25        0.006   0.051   0.294    0.308   0.154   0.113   0.164   0.036   0.052   0.011        25
 24            0.024   0.099    0.234   0.243   0.238   0.143   0.058   0.118   0.050            24
 23        0.016   0.034   0.160    0.184   0.231   0.247   0.117   0.101   0.125   0.036        23
 22            0.047   0.110    0.203   0.284   0.334   0.281   0.091   0.213   0.118            22
 21        0.045   0.097   0.361    0.250   0.375   0.260   0.209   0.240   0.262   0.070        21
 20    0.017   0.132   0.246    0.520   0.219   0.365   0.370   0.225   0.198   0.163   0.032    20
 19        0.087   0.284   0.379    0.388   0.220   0.234   0.387   0.317   0.215   0.142        19
 18    0.030   0.204   0.383    0.399   0.168   0.220   0.242   0.404   0.283   0.304   0.054    18
 17        0.104   0.297   0.280    0.165   0.298   0.301   0.282   0.552   0.348   0.185        17
 16    0.031   0.205   0.212    0.119   0.154   0.271   0.248   0.459   0.387   0.265   0.061    16
 15        0.090   0.261   0.111    0.103   0.380   0.300   0.403   0.439   0.232   0.173        15
 14    0.023   0.137   0.169    0.107   0.219   0.443   0.413   0.265   0.259   0.248   0.052    14
 13        0.053   0.143   0.221    0.256   0.437   0.435   0.302   0.146   0.135   0.134        13
 12    0.012   0.062   0.281    0.123   0.234   0.349   0.304   0.091   0.114   0.140   0.035    12
 11        0.039   0.146   0.219    0.122   0.358   0.397   0.143   0.077   0.164   0.109        11
 10            0.121   0.216    0.064   0.215   0.244   0.321   0.058   0.231   0.228            10
  9        0.044   0.278   0.178    0.072   0.208   0.214   0.133   0.154   0.280   0.096         9
  8            0.146   0.335    0.129   0.119   0.297   0.129   0.216   0.197   0.156             8
  7        0.027   0.227   0.341    0.165   0.242   0.113   0.258   0.410   0.113   0.032         7
  6            0.066   0.231    0.329   0.207   0.142   0.158   0.439   0.195   0.046             6
  5                0.097   0.147    0.358   0.202   0.175   0.276   0.396   0.064                 5
  4                    0.080    0.152   0.369   0.175   0.379   0.249   0.146                     4
  3                0.021   0.046    0.184   0.316   0.345   0.331   0.124   0.030                 3
  2                    0.020    0.054   0.231   0.185   0.239   0.112   0.036                     2
  1                        0.014    0.084   0.167   0.161   0.137   0.026                         1
  0                             0.022   0.091   0.092   0.086   0.034                             0
 -1                                 0.025   0.055   0.052   0.031                                -1
 -2                                             0.021                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel averaged  boundary  thermal fluxes    core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                              0.11                                            34
 33                                  0.15    0.27    0.27    0.14                                33
 32                              0.22    0.42    0.53    0.41    0.19                            32
 31                         0.23     0.57    0.71    0.70    0.52    0.20                        31
 30                     0.21     0.71    0.85    1.03    0.82    0.57    0.18                    30
 29                 0.13    0.71     1.06    1.10    1.13    0.95    0.55    0.14                29
 28                     0.60     1.23    1.22    1.40    1.23    0.96    0.51                    28
 27                 0.44    1.16     1.46    1.32    1.57    1.34    0.91    0.42                27
 26             0.25    0.98     1.58    1.50    1.64    1.64    1.31    0.84    0.28            26
 25         0.11    0.79    1.50     1.72    1.64    1.79    1.59    1.27    0.74    0.13        25
 24             0.53    1.37     1.91    1.76    1.74    1.84    1.66    1.17    0.58            24
 23         0.23    1.08    1.85     2.07    1.82    1.84    1.93    1.63    1.09    0.32        23
 22             0.73    1.64     2.05    2.07    1.92    1.95    1.99    1.51    0.87            22
 21         0.36    1.30    1.84     2.21    2.15    2.04    2.20    1.86    1.38    0.56        21
 20     0.10    0.82    1.76     1.73    2.47    2.25    2.15    2.18    1.85    1.18    0.19    20
 19         0.45    1.25    1.92     2.23    2.59    2.39    2.18    1.93    1.70    0.70        19
 18     0.15    0.80    1.57     2.11    2.62    2.60    2.37    2.02    1.89    1.22    0.24    18
 17         0.48    1.10    1.92     2.49    2.57    2.44    2.22    1.65    1.59    0.73        17
 16     0.16    0.81    1.54     2.28    2.59    2.59    2.42    2.07    1.76    1.20    0.26    16
 15         0.50    1.21    1.93     2.38    2.46    2.42    2.27    2.00    1.55    0.71        15
 14     0.16    0.92    1.68     2.13    2.37    2.31    2.25    2.38    1.87    1.15    0.24    14
 13         0.52    1.41    1.87     2.08    2.16    2.18    2.27    2.25    1.62    0.69        13
 12     0.12    0.96    1.66     2.09    2.04    2.15    2.15    2.37    1.98    1.20    0.19    12
 11         0.43    1.40    1.91     2.08    1.96    2.08    2.27    2.22    1.59    0.58        11
 10             0.81    1.74     2.12    1.95    2.13    2.02    2.32    1.86    0.99            10
  9         0.25    1.15    1.97     2.13    1.93    2.13    2.17    2.19    1.37    0.38         9
  8             0.56    1.44     2.13    2.07    2.02    1.94    2.26    1.83    0.76             8
  7         0.11    0.82    1.67     2.13    2.01    2.11    2.06    1.94    1.21    0.17         7
  6             0.27    1.09     1.84    2.10    2.16    2.09    2.00    1.53    0.45             6
  5                 0.48    1.37     1.80    2.07    2.12    2.09    1.61    0.77                 5
  4                     0.71     1.50    1.71    2.00    1.87    1.80    0.98                     4
  3                 0.16    0.84     1.42    1.59    1.69    1.58    1.15    0.27                 3
  2                     0.25     0.91    1.19    1.48    1.45    1.13    0.37                     2
  1                         0.27     0.78    1.01    1.12    0.94    0.43                         1
  0                              0.28    0.59    0.78    0.72    0.36                             0
 -1                                  0.21    0.39    0.42    0.25                                -1
 -2                                              0.17                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel ave boundary fast flux (triangle)   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.05244scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                              0.02                                            34
 33                                  0.04    0.05    0.04    0.01                                33
 32                              0.05    0.11    0.08    0.06    0.01                            32
 31                         0.04     0.17    0.16    0.13    0.05    0.00                        31
 30                     0.03     0.17    0.27    0.15    0.16    0.01    0.00                    30
 29                 0.02    0.13     0.32    0.28    0.23    0.08    0.00    0.00                29
 28                     0.10     0.28    0.35    0.16    0.22    0.02    0.01                    28
 27                 0.05    0.24     0.34    0.24    0.13    0.09    0.01    0.01                27
 26             0.02    0.15     0.37    0.23    0.12    0.12    0.04    0.03    0.02            26
 25         0.01    0.05    0.29     0.30    0.15    0.11    0.14    0.04    0.05    0.01        25
 24             0.02    0.10     0.24    0.23    0.22    0.14    0.06    0.11    0.05            24
 23         0.01    0.03    0.17     0.18    0.24    0.24    0.12    0.10    0.12    0.03        23
 22             0.05    0.11     0.22    0.27    0.33    0.26    0.09    0.20    0.12            22
 21         0.04    0.10    0.35     0.25    0.36    0.27    0.21    0.22    0.24    0.06        21
 20     0.02    0.13    0.25     0.50    0.22    0.34    0.35    0.22    0.20    0.16    0.03    20
 19         0.09    0.28    0.40     0.37    0.22    0.23    0.37    0.32    0.22    0.14        19
 18     0.03    0.20    0.38     0.39    0.17    0.22    0.24    0.41    0.28    0.30    0.05    18
 17         0.10    0.31    0.28     0.17    0.27    0.27    0.29    0.55    0.34    0.19        17
 16     0.03    0.20    0.22     0.13    0.15    0.27    0.25    0.46    0.40    0.27    0.06    16
 15         0.09    0.25    0.11     0.10    0.37    0.30    0.39    0.44    0.24    0.17        15
 14     0.02    0.14    0.17     0.11    0.22    0.43    0.40    0.27    0.25    0.24    0.05    14
 13         0.05    0.14    0.20     0.22    0.43    0.43    0.29    0.15    0.13    0.13        13
 12     0.01    0.06    0.26     0.13    0.24    0.36    0.31    0.09    0.11    0.14    0.03    12
 11         0.04    0.15    0.20     0.12    0.34    0.38    0.14    0.08    0.16    0.10        11
 10             0.12    0.22     0.07    0.20    0.24    0.30    0.06    0.21    0.22            10
  9         0.04    0.28    0.18     0.07    0.21    0.21    0.13    0.15    0.27    0.08         9
  8             0.15    0.33     0.14    0.12    0.27    0.14    0.22    0.20    0.16             8
  7         0.03    0.23    0.33     0.16    0.22    0.11    0.24    0.40    0.11    0.03         7
  6             0.06    0.23     0.31    0.21    0.14    0.16    0.43    0.19    0.04             6
  5                 0.09    0.16     0.34    0.20    0.18    0.28    0.39    0.06                 5
  4                     0.08     0.15    0.36    0.17    0.36    0.25    0.15                     4
  3                 0.02    0.05     0.18    0.30    0.33    0.32    0.12    0.03                 3
  2                     0.02     0.05    0.23    0.19    0.24    0.11    0.04                     2
  1                         0.02     0.08    0.17    0.16    0.14    0.03                         1
  0                              0.02    0.08    0.09    0.08    0.03                             0
 -1                                  0.02    0.05    0.05    0.03                                -1
 -2                                              0.02                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel ave boundary thermal flux (triangle)   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.05scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                              0.11                                            34
 33                                  0.14    0.24    0.23    0.13                                33
 32                              0.21    0.39    0.53    0.37    0.18                            32
 31                         0.23     0.57    0.71    0.70    0.52    0.19                        31
 30                     0.21     0.70    0.85    1.02    0.82    0.58    0.18                    30
 29                 0.13    0.71     1.05    1.10    1.14    0.96    0.56    0.13                29
 28                     0.60     1.21    1.21    1.40    1.25    0.98    0.51                    28
 27                 0.41    1.16     1.44    1.33    1.58    1.35    0.93    0.39                27
 26             0.24    0.98     1.56    1.49    1.66    1.66    1.34    0.86    0.25            26
 25         0.11    0.79    1.51     1.73    1.65    1.81    1.64    1.30    0.74    0.13        25
 24             0.53    1.39     1.90    1.79    1.77    1.85    1.69    1.19    0.58            24
 23         0.22    1.11    1.86     2.09    1.82    1.87    1.96    1.65    1.09    0.29        23
 22             0.73    1.66     2.05    2.10    1.93    1.98    2.03    1.53    0.87            22
 21         0.34    1.31    1.85     2.21    2.18    2.03    2.21    1.89    1.40    0.51        21
 20     0.10    0.82    1.75     1.76    2.49    2.29    2.19    2.19    1.86    1.17    0.17    20
 19         0.45    1.25    1.88     2.26    2.61    2.41    2.21    1.94    1.70    0.70        19
 18     0.15    0.80    1.58     2.11    2.66    2.62    2.40    2.02    1.87    1.23    0.24    18
 17         0.48    1.10    1.94     2.52    2.63    2.50    2.21    1.67    1.60    0.73        17
 16     0.16    0.81    1.53     2.30    2.63    2.60    2.43    2.07    1.75    1.19    0.25    16
 15         0.51    1.22    1.97     2.43    2.49    2.42    2.29    2.00    1.54    0.71        15
 14     0.16    0.92    1.69     2.15    2.39    2.33    2.27    2.39    1.90    1.16    0.23    14
 13         0.52    1.42    1.92     2.13    2.18    2.19    2.30    2.28    1.64    0.69        13
 12     0.12    0.98    1.69     2.10    2.03    2.13    2.13    2.42    2.01    1.20    0.17    12
 11         0.40    1.41    1.95     2.11    1.98    2.11    2.30    2.27    1.60    0.54        11
 10             0.81    1.73     2.16    1.99    2.14    2.06    2.38    1.90    0.99            10
  9         0.24    1.16    1.98     2.18    1.94    2.14    2.21    2.22    1.39    0.33         9
  8             0.56    1.44     2.14    2.11    2.07    1.96    2.27    1.83    0.77             8
  7         0.12    0.82    1.69     2.15    2.05    2.15    2.10    1.96    1.21    0.17         7
  6             0.25    1.09     1.85    2.11    2.19    2.12    2.02    1.52    0.40             6
  5                 0.45    1.37     1.83    2.08    2.14    2.08    1.62    0.71                 5
  4                     0.71     1.49    1.73    2.02    1.90    1.78    0.98                     4
  3                 0.16    0.85     1.42    1.61    1.72    1.60    1.16    0.24                 3
  2                     0.25     0.89    1.19    1.48    1.43    1.14    0.37                     2
  1                         0.28     0.78    1.01    1.12    0.94    0.41                         1
  0                              0.27    0.54    0.78    0.66    0.36                             0
 -1                                  0.19    0.34    0.37    0.23                                -1
 -2                                              0.17                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
```

I want to be able to enter a location on the map, for example b27, and have Python go through each map file in the 'inputs/' folder and extract the number at that location along with the map name and core date and output it to a .csv file.  So typing b27 will output something like:

```
          channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes     channel averaged  cell avg  thermal fluxes
171203fl  0.053                                       0.44
171204fl  0.051                                       0.41
171205fl  0.060                                       0.52
```

And so on, 171203fl, 171204fl, and 171205fl being the names of the text/map files where the numbers were extracted from.

I am new to Python.  Is this possible?  Would I use something like pandas and treat each map like a dataframe with columns and rows?  So far I have written:

```
import glob
import pathlib
import pandas as pd; pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 150, 'display.colheader_justify', 'left')

files = glob.glob('inputs/*')

df = pd.read_csv(files)

column = input('Enter column [a-y]:')
row = input('Enter row [-2 to 34]:')
```

But I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use pandas to read that, because it's clearly not a csv.  You need to utilize the spacing of the data, and you lose that if you convert it.

```
import os

letters = "yzabcdefghjklmnopqrst"

val = 'b27'

col = 9 + letters.index(val[0])*3
row = int(val[1:])

data = []
for filename in os.listdir('inputs'):
    fn = 'inputs/'+filename
    for line in open(fn):
        if len(line) < 10:
            continue
        i = line.find('core')
        if i >= 0:
            label = line[:i-1].strip()
            core = line[i+5:i+13]
            if not data or data[-1]['core'] != core:
                data.append( {'core': core} )
            continue
        if line[2].isdigit() and int(line[:3].strip()) == row:
            data[-1][label] = float(line[col:col+6].strip())

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'channel ave boundary fast flux (triangle)': 0.05,
  'channel ave boundary thermal flux (triangle)': 0.41,
  'channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes': 0.053,
  'channel averaged  boundary  thermal fluxes': 0.44,
  'channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes': 0.053,
  'channel averaged  cell avg  thermal fluxes': 0.44,
  'core': '171203fl'}]
```

That can be converted to pandas, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks.

Sorry, I accidentally uploaded the wrong input file.  I uploaded the correct one now.  The correct one has some extra text at the top of each map that throws your code off a little.

Would I be better off first having Python copy and paste the first two maps ('channel averaged cell avg fast fluxes' and 'channel averaged cell avg thermal fluxes' to a separate file and then having the program act on those files, extracting the numbers from each map?

Comment: No.  Are you saying you ONLY care about the "cell  avg" values and can ignore the rest?  If so, just exit the loop  `if 'boundary' in line: break`.  Easy.

Comment: No, I want all the values for a particular site that the user specifies (eg. H11), from all the maps (channel averaged cell avg fast fluxes, channel averaged cell avg thermal fluxes, etc.).

Comment: So, you just need to parse the line containing "core" by splitting into words.  Look for the word "core".  The word after that is the core ID, the words before that are your column label.